# AngularJS : watch array property

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, inheritance, properties

The problem is clearly visible here http://plnkr.co/edit/ZphAKvZeoVtuGFSEmOKg?p=preview

Let's say you have an array that looks like this

```
var arr = [
 {
   'a': "123",
   'b': "654"
 },
 {
   'a': "456",
   'b': "321"
 }
];

arr.foo = 'bar';
```

`$watch` **will** fire when you change something inside them objects(like so for example `arr[0].a = 'hoopidoo'`), but it **won't** when you change `foo`(like so for example `arr.foo = 'deedlilaa'`, or via `ng-model`.)

Could it be javascripts limitation? I mean when you iterate over that array, you'd only get back the objects, so there's no way to enumerate that `foo`..

Check the plunker to see what I'm about anyway. Watch won't fire no matter what you type in the input or what you do in the controller.

Comment: what you wrote isnt even valid javascript , try to paste the "array" into nodejs repl,it wont work, foo:'bar' cant be an element of a javascript array. You can only define foo as a property of an object,since an array is an object.

Comment: I thought it was possible to write it down like this, but if not.. anyway it's still correct in the plunker, or here http://jsfiddle.net/6S738/

Comment: You changed your question , i'm refeering to revision 1 : http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20621906/revisions , revision 1 code doesnt compile , it's not valid javascript.

Comment: I know, and I was answering your comment, I thought it was possible to write it down as it was written down in rev 3, but since it's not possible I corrected it(to match the stuff that's on plunker) and told you.

Comment: no problem my friend, we are here to help , dont worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to observe Array object properties (in opposite to objects at a specific key) is to `$watch` them explicitly:

```
$scope.$watch('arr.param', function(newVal, oldVal) {
   // Some code
}
arr.param = 'foobar'
```

However, if you don't care about mixing numeric and associative array keys, you could just change Line 37 of your plunker to something like this:

```
$scope.arr['param'] = "abc";
```

Comment: I do unfortunately, I'm using the array in an `ng-repeat` and I only want the actual objects to show up in it, those properties are kind of helpers..

Comment: Then, I suggest you explicitly watch the Array object properties you want. Afaik there's no other solution to your problem.

Comment: Either that or ng-change on the input that has this property, that would call the same function that watch does.

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
$scope.$watchCollection
```

in particular you can watch the variabile inside the scope using $watchColletion and update your buttons or anything you need.

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function () {
    if ($scope.myForm)
        return $scope.myForm;
}, function () {
   if ($scope.myForm)
   if (($scope.myForm.$invalid == true))
          $scope.formValidityChange(true);
    else
        $scope.formValidityChange(false);
}, true);
```

this will check all the variabiles that change inside the form and you will update the controller. i think u can also check what is changed by comparing the two objects maybe this can be more difficult.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript arrays don't allow "string indexes". `arr.foo` will convert the type of `arr` from `Array` to `Object`.

Comment: Might have confused you, and myself as well, with the way I wrote it down on SA, which was completely invalid javascript. It was correct on the plunker though. I have updated the question.

Comment: `a = [];
a.foo = 1;
Array.isArray(a); // true
a instanceof Array; // true`